pointer or reference to incomplete type "altcp_tls_config" is not allowed C/C++
I am trying to set up an HTTPS server with lwip and embedtls on a raspberry pico 2w.

void MyHTTPServer::start() {
    tls_config = altcp_tls_create_config_server_privkey_cert(
        reinterpret_cast<const u8_t*>(server_key), server_key_len, NULL, 0, reinterpret_cast<const u8_t*>(server_cert), server_cert_len
    );
    mbedtls_x509_crt_parse(tls_config->cert, CA_CERT, sizeof(CA_CERT));

    
    if (!tls_config) {
        printf("Failed to create TLS configuration\n");
        return;
    }

    // Update SSI tags to match exactly what's in the HTML
    static const char *ssi_tags[] = {
        "Key1",     // <!--#Key1-->
        "Value1",   // <!--#Value1--> 
        "Key2",     // <!--#Key2-->
        "Value2"    // <!--#Value2-->
    };

    http_set_ssi_handler(ssi_handler, ssi_tags, 
                        sizeof(ssi_tags) / sizeof(ssi_tags[0]));
    printf("SSI handler and tags registered\n");
    
    start_cgi();
    httpd_inits(tls_config);
    printf("HTTPS server started\n");
}

My VS Code flags tls_config->cert: mbedtls_x509_crt_parse(tls_config->cert, ca_cert, ca_cert_len);
pointer or reference to incomplete type "altcp_tls_config" is not allowedC/C++(833)
I tried to set it up similarly to this blog post: https://mcuapplab.blogspot.com/2023/12/raspberry-pi-pico-w-lwip-mbedtls-ep1.html
I used xxd -i file > file.h to create the header files containing the certificates. I've also set up a basic mbedtls_config.h:

/* Workaround for some mbedtls source files using INT_MAX without including limits.h */
#include <limits.h>

#define MBEDTLS_NO_PLATFORM_ENTROPY
#define MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_HARDWARE_ALT

#define MBEDTLS_SSL_IN_CONTENT_LEN    2048
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_OUT_CONTENT_LEN    2048
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_MAX_CONTENT_LEN    2048

#define MBEDTLS_ALLOW_PRIVATE_ACCESS
#define MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME
#define MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME_DATE

#define MBEDTLS_CIPHER_MODE_CBC
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP192R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP224R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP384R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP521R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP192K1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP224K1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256K1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP256R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP384R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP512R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_CURVE25519_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_RSA_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_PKCS1_V15
#define MBEDTLS_SHA256_SMALLER
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_SERVER_NAME_INDICATION
#define MBEDTLS_AES_C
#define MBEDTLS_ASN1_PARSE_C
#define MBEDTLS_BIGNUM_C
#define MBEDTLS_CIPHER_C
#define MBEDTLS_CTR_DRBG_C
#define MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_C
#define MBEDTLS_ERROR_C
#define MBEDTLS_MD_C
#define MBEDTLS_MD5_C
#define MBEDTLS_OID_C
#define MBEDTLS_PKCS5_C
#define MBEDTLS_PK_C
#define MBEDTLS_PK_PARSE_C
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_C
#define MBEDTLS_RSA_C
#define MBEDTLS_SHA1_C
#define MBEDTLS_SHA224_C
#define MBEDTLS_SHA256_C
#define MBEDTLS_SHA512_C
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_CLI_C
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_SRV_C
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_TLS_C
#define MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C
#define MBEDTLS_X509_USE_C
#define MBEDTLS_AES_FEWER_TABLES

/* TLS 1.2 */
#define MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1_2
#define MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDHE_ECDSA_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_GCM_C
#define MBEDTLS_ECDH_C
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_C
#define MBEDTLS_ECDSA_C
#define MBEDTLS_ASN1_WRITE_C

// The following is needed to parse a certificate
#define MBEDTLS_PEM_PARSE_C
#define MBEDTLS_BASE64_C

I expect it to work. This should be a working configuration. Since there's not much information material online, I was unable to fix it myself.
The only I could find so far were these two videos from somewhere in Taiwan:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6e7X4dYlQi0&t=430s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qu3BRHyAwfw
As of now, I don't need sessions implemented only a working https server connection.
I created the certificates by using the commands of the blog post I provided above.
